# How to use if then replace with a range in excel vba? error 13 given

Tags: excel

I am trying to change some values between a range with the following code:

```
Sub selection()

    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant
    Dim fx As Variant
    fnd = 7
    rplc = "007"
    fx = 167
    
    
    Set rng3 = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K2").End(xlDown))
    rng3.TextToColumns
    If rng3.Value = fnd Then
    rng3.Replace what:=fnd, replacement:=rplc, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    MatchCase:=False
    ElseIf rng3.Value = fx Then
    End If

End Sub
```

I am looking for value 7 in rng3 but I realized that there where values like 167 that appeared, so with the method `rng3.Replace what:=fnd, replacement:=rplc` it will also change this value so i got an if condition so when `rng3.Value = fnd` go and replace, `elseif rng3.Value = fx` then do nothing. With this it gives me an error 13 types don't match, so i'm guessing because im puting rng3 as a range it doesn't allow the if condition. Any help what can I use to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with a for each loop. We add another another variable with `dim r as Range` and then we use this:

```
For Each r In rng3
    If r.Value = fnd Then
        r.Value = rplc
    ElseIf r.Value = fx Then
    End If
Next r
```

That we go and replace the 7 where is found, the 167 won't change.